# Browsing path in Delphi XE4 doesn't function the way Embarcadero says

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe4

The Embarcadero website describes the Delphi Browsing path as follows:

Browsing path
Specifies the directories where the Code Browsing feature of the Code Editor looks for unit files when it cannot find an identifier on the project search path or source path.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Code_Editor

I have some DevExpress components and the paths to the .pas files are in my browsing path. Somehow, the code browser doesn't find these files. I also cannot step into these files when debugging. Only the .dcu files are in my library path.

Is the Embarcadero website wrong?

People seem to say adding the path to the .dcu should be enough to step into the .pas when debug .dcus is set to True: 
[Organizing the search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780831/organizing-the-search-path/782162#782162)

I don't find that to be true. What's up with that?

Comment: Sounds like the DCU's are not built with debug info. Then stepping in them is not possible, even if you have the source.

Comment: Ah! Good point. I believe that the .dcus were generated through the DevExpress installer (.exe) and have not been compiled by the IDE, so even though I have debug .dcus set to true it is not effecting the already compiled package .dcus.

Comment: Why are you linking .dcus? Isn't it better to include the source files in your project? Or are you using runtime packages?

Comment: We're in the process of moving an old project to XE4. The default setting of the DevExpress installer is to link .dcus, not to recompile the package source files when the project recompiles. We've now changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is accurate. It correctly describes the browsing path.

However, it's not uncommon for the IDE to get confused. If the project doesn't compile then code browsing doesn't work. Often a full re-build will be enough to make code browsing work again. But sometimes that's not enough. In which case any attempt to help solve your problem would likely require an SSCCE.

But as to the question you asked, the documentation is correct in its description of the browsing path.

Comment: This is useful information for others who have trouble using the code browser. My particular, problem was as @Marco van de Voort said: while I had debug .dcus set to true, the .dcus in question had not been compiled since they were created with the DevExpress installer.